# On scroll zoom out slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you open this link https://vimeo.com/cameo and scroll the page, you will see that the image goes to iPhone.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic).

Those libraries help to simplify creating parallax and dynamic websites.

Maybe this comparison will help you to choose the right one for you: [Skrollr vs. ScrollMagic](https://ihatetomatoes.net/skrollr-vs-scrollmagic/).

Comment: have you seen my reference link ?

Comment: Of course I did. It's just a very big image whose size is relative to the scrolling. That's all possible with either [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic)

Comment: Thanks :)  is there any easy way or this is easy with this plug in  ?

Comment: because i am doing a project same as that one i can create whole site except the very beginning. :(

Comment: I would say it's relatively easy. Take a look at [the examples](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/tree/master/examples) and at this tutorial: https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

Comment: This [positioning guide](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/guide/anchor-position-guide.pdf) helped me very much in the beginning.

Comment: so nice of you :)  may be i need help of some senior persons but i will give it a try :)

Comment: You're welcome :D. Could you be so kind to consider marking my answer as accepted?